# Integrating WP E-commerce plugin into custom theme

Tags: plugins, customization

I am getting very worried now, since I'm seeing almost NOTHING about integrating GetShopped's WP Ecommerce plugin into a custom theme. I'm using all custom template pages, and would like to use shortcodes to display items for sale, shopping cart, checkout links, etc etc. I've been to their forum, and cannot find anything about using with a custom theme. Their documentation isn't much at all. I've only been able to find one example of a shortcode that I can use, which is

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[wpsc_products category_id="awesome"]' ); ?>
```

That actually works fine, and am able to show any items with a category of "awesome". But that's it! I can't find any other shortcodes. Like shopping cart, checkout, etc etc.   One of my main concerns/needs is to be able to make a custom button(not part of the plugin) that I've styled myself, and have the customer be brought to an items page, when clicked.   Is anyone out there an expert with this plugin, or know of some place I can get help with this? Ugh. I'm very worried now, since I've been building this site thinking that It was going to be much easier to integrate this plugin into it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi ... did you try the Docs on the Get Shopped website at http://docs.getshopped.org/category/developer-documentation/design-and-layout/short-codes/

Comment: Yeah, I did, but it just doesn't help out much. It seems like most people use this plugin with a theme built around it, or just go with the default pages that it creates for you. Stupidly, I have built and planned out a lot for my current project based on this plugin and it's add-ons. Many of those add-ons are premium and so I would like to stick with using them.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your questions ...

1. The [user documentation is very detailed at Get Shopped](http://docs.getshopped.org/)
2. There are a [number of articles for theme designers and developers](http://docs.getshopped.org/category/developer-documentation/design-and-layout/template-tags/) to work their way through  [and here too](http://docs.getshopped.org/category/developer-documentation/design-and-layout/)
3. You probably really want to read the [conditional tag articles](http://docs.getshopped.org/category/developer-documentation/design-and-layout/conditional-tags/) to include in your custom theme
4. Had you found the the WP-ecommerce templates located at `/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-theme' you'll find these easiest for integrating

[image: WPecommerce templates]

If you've got this far in the design process, I sympathise with you ... but really ... Why design first and build last when it seems you've not used the product before?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your reply. Just not seeing what I'm looking for. For example, I would like to create a product, and then be able to show that product and all the information that goes with it(title,price, description, photo etc) in a certain spot of my custom template. Just like I'm doing with throwing in the WP loop in whichever spot in my template I want my latest post to show up at. Does that make sense? Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: look at the template `wpsc-single_product.php` that should be what you need

Comment: Thank you sir. So I've started playing around with some things, and odd things are happening. So within my custom template page, I'm attempting to use this: (php tags stripped of course)  include 'wpsc-single_product.php' and whats happening is that it's actually pulling in part of a blog post instead of bringing in the product I've created.     Then, just trying to experiment and figure things out, I've tried:
              echo wpsc_the_product_title ();   and I would think it would pull in the title of my product, but instead pulls in the title of the custom template page it's on. I'm lost!